# Selenium Python library can't find elements on login page

Tags: python, selenium

I am attempting to make a web scraper for the Cisco Webex control hub. Since the login page and subsequent pages use Javascript I am using the Selenium Python library to accomplish this. Unfortunately, I am unable to find the text box and sign in button elements with Selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# ブラウザを開く。
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://admin.webex.com')

driver.find_element_by_class_name('md-input ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched').send_keys('email@address.com')

driver.find_element_by_class_name('md-panel__cta').click()
```

I don't have much code yet, but I have tried every way to find the elements, but nothing I tried has worked. Is there any reason why I can't find the elements?

I have moved on ahead and finished the code for the password entry page. However, how Cisco has made each page is different so I was unable to reuse the code from the password entry section on the username entry code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue was page loading. Induce some waits or you'll miss the element.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.md-input"))).send_keys("email@address.com")
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

when an element has more than one class, it will not be a good idea to locate element with class like this `find_element_by_class_name('md-input ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched')`.

In this case, xpath or cssSelector is a good choice:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='email']")
```

Comment: Please accept and up vote if it solves your problem, it will help others and myself in turn. If not working, let me know, I will try again.